# C# 7.2 const vs referenced(in) readonly field in function parameters passing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, c#-7.2

let's say i have a class with:
a const

```
private const decimal x = 2.0m;
```

a readonly field

```
private readonly decimal y = 2.0m;
```

a method with this signature

```
void Method1(in decimal x)
```

if i invoke the Method1 with the const x Method1(x) i assume the value of x will passed by value, instead when i use the Method1 with the readonly y Method1(in y) the value will be passed by readonly reference. So my expectations are that  the more performant is the readonly field used as a "fake" const. I'm wrong? i have some dubt that internally the const will be used, by the compilator or optimized by the clr, to be performant as the readonly field passed by reference.

Comment: "the more performant" Why not simply measure it? But do a benchmark-test, this is execute it in a loop some millions of times. Doing it only once won´t show you realistic results. Anyway I think the difference - if any at all - is neglectable.

Comment: The statements are *not* equivalent. A const will disappear during compilation. The compiler can and *will* replace any reference to it with its actual value. In fact that's one of the gotchas - if *any* assembly depends on that constant, *all* of them will have to be recompiled or end up using different values. `Constant` is supposed to be constant for good

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in fact if you actually decompile the above situation you will see that using the in keyword will make a difference. So it only kind of disappears but have a look: [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANAJiA1AHwK4GcCWA7A5gAgGUBPdAFwFMBbAbgFgAoDHAk86gOgBUALAJwoBDOC26D0Aa3T0GjbIKoV0AB0EBjCkTJ9UasoUwAvClyVl8jAN6N8t/GoA249PgAKfAPa4+Ciwzv41v4BdsqowA6YavgAbh6YcPgAsoI4ABQAlDYhtkE5OQBmaWAZMvkhRcSl2TkAvjUhDQHKfJgxgpT45B1RsfGJRTj4cBRqmFSCDrGTWcE5eeV2TXb1c41rza3tnQLCHtgOxMOj45P4YPgAvPgATBwADLTLti1tHZpq++THYxNTR9c7o8yitGLUgA==)

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410723/is-there-a-difference-between-private-const-and-private-readonly-variables-in-c

Comment: Check the related [What is the difference between const and readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-readonly).

Comment: Bear in mind [`const decimal` is a lie anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51607247/15498)

Comment: @RobinB That copy is one of the well-known gotchas of using `in` and `ref`. It's not `in` that creates the copy here. The *compiler* isn't sure that the value won't change so it *copies* it to ensure it won't. There's at least one Roslyn analyzer that looks for such problems

Comment: @RobinB found it : [ErrorProne.NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/05/03/avoiding-struct-and-readonly-reference-performance-pitfalls-with-errorprone-net/)

Comment: i know the difference between const and readonly field, my question was wich is the more performant to use. BTW i have do a test now, i will send a response asap

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well thats interesting thanks

Comment: @MarcoLevarato instead of testing check Robin's link to Sharplab. The code has a problem unrelated to performance - it creates a *local copy* of the value, even with `const`, to ensure it won't change

Comment: @MarcoLevarato Sergey Teplyakov wrote several articles that explain the perf pitfals, and even wrote a [Roslyn Analyzer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/05/03/avoiding-struct-and-readonly-reference-performance-pitfalls-with-errorprone-net/) for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have do a test and the winner is the readonly field passed with in, this is the code executed with a i7 8700k processor

```
class Test
{
    public const decimal x = 0.2m;
    public readonly decimal y = 0.2m;

    public void Method1(in decimal x)
    {
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Test();

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            t.Method1(in t.y);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        sw.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            t.Method1(Test.x);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.ReadLine();
     } 
}
```

The method invoked as t.Method1(in t.y); have consumed 11606428 ticks,
The method invoked as t.Method1(Test.x); have consumed 16963941 ticks

So there are not optimizations under the hood for the const in this case

Comment: There's nothing to optimize - in both cases you asked for a ref to something. Something has to exist then, whether as a field or local copy. If the parameterd wasn't a `ref`, you'd see that the constant value was inlined to ` f(2m);`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, probably the *readonly* option is more performant, but its debatable as to wether this performance gain is relevant or not.

Why?

The `const` version will actually run the decimal constructor every time the method is invoked, while the readonly / in version will simply copy a reference to a previously created decimal instance. The latter is obviously faster.

You can verify this by simply inspecting the IL:

- Const version:

  ```
  IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 20
  IL_0003: ldc.i4.0
  IL_0004: ldc.i4.0
  IL_0005: ldc.i4.0
  IL_0006: ldc.i4.1
  IL_0007: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32, int32, int32, bool, uint8)
  IL_000c: call instance bool C::Method2(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
  ```
- The readonly/in version:

  ```
  IL_0002: ldflda valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal C::dd
  IL_0007: call instance bool C::Method1(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal&)
  IL_000c: pop
  ```

That said, I'm not altogether sure why you tie `const` with performance. A `const` is a way to convey in your code that a given value *will not change ever*. `const` does not mean, this value stored as a constant will be more performant when used.

Unless you really have an emprically demonstrated performance issue that is solved by this marginal (at best) optimization, a value that is logically a constant, should be a `const`, and a variable that is logically a read only value should be `readonly` and all other considerations should be ignored. If your case is the former then document it clearly in your code why a logically constant value is implemented as a read only field.

Comment: all is relevant in some conext as the my. I'm writing a HFT bot

Comment: @MarcoLevarato then you are looking for the wrong thing. A `decimal` is already read-only. And ultrapremature optimizations like this can lead to perf degradation, as the answers here show. Better sorting, grouping algorithms will lead to *far* better perf for HFT. Better containers, avoiding wasted operations, better algorithms etc

Comment: @MarcoLevarato Of course all is relevant to some extent. But if this issue is a real and measured performance concern then maybe the issue here is that you are not using the most adequate framework... maybe a non managed environment is the better choice?

Comment: @MarcoLevarato remember someone trying to find the last value above a threashold in an HFT application. Wrote it in C++ for perf. Then started iterating from the *start* instead of the *end* to find the *last* value. Replacing these with reverse iterators, adding maps (dictionaries), using the proper containers and algorithms resulted in 10x improvement at least. No pointer arithmetic could do that